# Claudia.js jasmine post/put body key

Tags: jasmine-node, claudiajs

I'm using claudia-api-builder and attempting to write tests using jasmine-node. I'm using the proxyRouter on my API using this tutorial https://claudiajs.com/tutorials/testing-locally.html, and I can pass path parameters fine as demonstrated. However, I can't find what the key is for the body of the request.

For example it says

> You can fill in the other properties (eg queryStringParameters)
>   according to what the test expects

But I can't find anywhere that lists the possible properties. The API Gateway Proxy Object link also doesn't seem to go to anything useful, as the sample doesn't seem to include a body.

Does anybody know what the key I should be using is? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out - somewhat embarrassingly it's just `body`.